# What is best practice for connecting/coupling EMT conduit?

Tags: electrical, conduit

I'll be assembling some runs of 1/2" and 3/4" EMT in an unfinished garage in the coming weeks. I've got metal compression couplings and connectors. Aside from making sure the EMT ends are smooth and burr-free before assembly, are there any treatments/procedures in the assembly? Should I be doing any surface prep on the ends like emery paper? Measure the conduit resistance across the coupling to make sure the grounding bond is good? My Kopr-Shield joint compound encourages its use for raceway assembly, but maybe that is just to sell more pricey product?

Comment: I would not use emery paper or anything else that would remove the factory galvanizing. Also be sure to use a saw to cut conduit, and not a tubing cutter that leaves a sharp deformed edge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are over-thinking this.  While I'm sure you want to do the best job possible, this isn't a highly technical thing to do.  If you cut some EMT, de-burring is a good idea.   Make sure you don't have more than 360 degrees of bends in a particular run unless you have pull box in it someplace.   If you need a pull box, be sure it's metal if you intend to use the EMT as ground.

Comment: You're probably right. It's my Dad's garage so I don't want to make any mistakes. :) The runs should all be straight to other boxes or one right angle sweep.